# How to set the `running` attribute of concurrent.future.Future() object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

To learn the usage of asyncio, I have written the following code:

```
class MultiProcessor:
    def __init__(self, n) -> None:
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self._bg_thread = Thread(target=loop_forever, args=(self._loop, ), daemon=True)
        self._bg_thread.start()

    def submit(self, f, *args, **kwargs) -> asyncio.Future:
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(run_one_process(f, args, kwargs), self._loop)
        return fut

async def run_one_process(f, args, kwargs):
    q = mp.Queue()
    kwargs['q'] = q
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,daemon=True)
    p.start()

    while p.is_alive():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    res = q.get()
    p.close()
    return res

def test_func(a, b, **kwargs):
    print('start running')
    time.sleep(2)
    res = a + b
    kwargs['q'].put(res)

def loop_forever(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = MultiProcessor(4)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    fut = pool.submit(test_func, 1, 2)

    while not fut.done():
        print(fut.running())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

from the console I can see that the coroutine is indeed running, but when I print `fut.running()`, it always returns `False`. How can I set the `running` attr of the `Future` object?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, as I discovered when I looked into the standard library code.  The short answer to your question **How to set the `running` attribute of concurrent.future.Future() object?** is that you can't.  A somewhat longer answer is that you probably shouldn't even want to do that, since running() isn't a simple attribute but a function that returns an answer based on the internal state of the Future.  You don't want to mess with that.

There is a function `concurrent.futures.Future.set_running_or_notify_cancel`, which seems like it might do what you want. But its documentation includes this line:
"Should only be used by Executor implementations and unit tests." And they mean it.  In the case of an `Executor`, it does indeed get called at a logical time: when the `Executor` begins to execute the function that you passed to `submit`.

But in your program you don't have an Executor.  The function actually gets called when the asyncio task finishes, in other words, when `run_one_process` returns.  You can't get around this by calling `set_running_or_notify_cancel` yourself, for example inside the `submit` function.  That doesn't work - I tried it.  When asyncio at last gets around to calling `set_running_or_notify_cancel`, it thinks that the Future is in an invalid state and throws an Exception.  In other words, `set_running_or_notify_cancel` can only be called *once*, and since the asyncio code already does that, you cannot do it as well.

So `Future.is_running()` is only meaningful if the Future has been managed by an Executor.  You could reasonably regard this is a bug, either in asyncio or in the documentation.  The internal logic of the asyncio library is fairly complicated, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

I can think of two workarounds.  In your case, you could inherit your Multiprocessor class from concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.  It doesn't look to be very difficult to rewrite the rest of your script, but I haven't done it.

You could explicitly use a synchronization primitive to explicitly define the "running" state for your specific application.  I can think of some reasons to prefer this.  You could consider "running" to be the condition where the function has begun to execute in the secondary Process.  Or you could consider "running" to be the condition where the function `run_one_process` is executing.  If you write the code, you control this.

Here is a script that uses a threading.Event object to allow the main loop to tell when `run_one_process` is executing:

```
import asyncio
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import concurrent.futures
from threading import Thread, Event

class MultiProcessor:
    def __init__(self, n, evt: Event) -> None:
        self._evt = evt
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self._bg_thread = Thread(target=loop_forever, args=(self._loop, ),
                                 daemon=True)
        self._bg_thread.start()

    def submit(self, f, *args, **kwargs) -> concurrent.futures.Future:
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(run_one_process(f, args, kwargs),
                                                self._loop)
        self._evt.set()
        return fut

async def run_one_process(f, args, kwargs):
    print("run_one_process started")
    q = mp.Queue()
    kwargs['q'] = q
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,daemon=True)
    p.start()

    while p.is_alive():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    res = q.get()
    p.close()
    return res

def test_func(a, b, **kwargs):
    print('start running')
    time.sleep(2)
    res = a + b
    kwargs['q'].put(res)

def loop_forever(loop):
    print("Event loop thread started")
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    evt = Event()
    pool = MultiProcessor(4, evt)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    fut = pool.submit(test_func, 1, 2)

    while not fut.done():
        print(evt.is_set())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Mypy had a complaint with your original code: the function `submit` returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` object, not an `asyncio.Future` object.

Comment: Yes, I checked the src code of `multiprocessing` and found that too. I am thinking of adding a new attribute `running` to the `Future` object to bypass the limitation. But your way is worth trying too. Thanks for studying into it :)